# Fujitsu ScanSnap IX500 scanner stopped working, possibly on upgrade from Debian jessie to stretch

Tags: debian, sane

My ScanSnap IX500 stopped working recently, possibly on upgrade from Debian jessie to stretch.

Per the documentation in http://www.sane-project.org/man/sane-fujitsu.5.html I set the environmental variable `SANE_DEBUG_FUJITSU=5`and then ran `xsane`, I got:

```
fujitsu] sane_init: fujitsu backend 1.0.127, from sane-backends 1.0.25
[fujitsu] sane_get_devices: config option "buffer-size" (262144) is > 65536, warning!
[fujitsu] stat: return error 'Error during device I/O'
[fujitsu] WARNING: Brain-dead scanner. Hitting with stick 
[fujitsu] stat: return error 'Error during device I/O'
[fujitsu] WARNING: Brain-dead scanner. Hitting with stick again
[fujitsu] stat: return error 'Error during device I/O'
[fujitsu] wait_scanner: error 'Error during device I/O'
[fujitsu] connect_fd: could not wait_scanner
```

It shows up in `lsusb` as

```
Bus 004 Device 002: ID 04c5:132b Fujitsu, Ltd
```

It shows up intermittently in `scanimage -L`, but currently it's showing:

```
SANE_DEBUG_FUJITSU=15 scanimage -L

[fujitsu] attach_one: start
[fujitsu] attach_one: looking for 'libusb:003:015'
[fujitsu] connect_fd: start
[fujitsu] connect_fd: opening USB device
[fujitsu] connect_fd: could not open device: 3
[fujitsu] connect_fd: finish
```

Why is it not working? How do I fix it?

Note: the scanner is plugged into a USB 2 slot. I earlier had it plugged into a USB 3 slot. I tried switching it to a USB 2 slot because of some reports that USB 3 was the problem, but it's still not working.

See for example the bug reports: https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1297169
and
http://sane-devel.alioth.debian.narkive.com/kLQc0Aik/fujitsu-ix500-no-scanners-were-identified

In any case, a USB device should work regardless whether it's plugged into a USB 2 or USB 3 slot.

Thanks to Anthony (@derobert) for assistance debugging this.

It seems likely that `sane-backends` is the problem, and that downgrading or upgrading it will make the problem go away. stretch is using `1.0.25-4.1`, while jessie used `1.0.24-8+deb8u2`, and experimental has `1.0.27-1~experimental2`.

Also, unplugging it and then plugging it back in again seems to make it visible again for awhile. Which suggests the problem may not be with `sane-backends` and may be a USB issue.

Answer (score 1):

I also had this problem migrating from Raspbian (based on Debian) Stretch to Buster, with a previously working scanbd setup.

EDIT: Someone wanted to edit my answer to be `scandb`, but it is indeed [`scanbd`](https://packages.debian.org/buster/scanbd).

So far, I've discovered a few issues.

One issue seemed to be related to `scanbm.socket` getting a "port already in use" error that seems to be because `saned.socket` was using the same port; using systemctl to `stop` and `disable` the latter seems to have worked for this (the service files are virtually identical).

The other issue was a permissions issue -- no devices found with `scanimage -L`, but the scanner was properly detected with `sudo scanimage -L`. Using `sudo lsusb` followed by `ls -l /dev/bus/usb/BUSNUM/DEVNUM`, I could see that the scanner was owned by `root:saned`, but `grep saned /etc/group` showed that the `saned` group had no members. There was however a `scanner` group that contained the `saned` user. This matches up with an option in the `scanbd.conf` file that asks about dropping privileges to a specific user and group (scanner being one of the suggestions).

I found a `udev` service file at `/lib/udev/rules.d/99-saned.rules` that was changing the permissions on matched USB devices to have the group `saned`. I copied this to `/etc/udev/rules.d/99-saned.rules` and modified it to use the group `scanner` instead of `saned`. I don't know if this udev rule changed between stretch and buster, but changing it and rebooting seems to have restored my ability to use scanbd.

Comment: Thanks, changing the group for the sane device magically worked on upgrade from stretch to buster. Note: Use `getfacl` on the device to see the current group.
`getfacl /dev/bus/usb/001/004`

Answer (score 0):

I just exactly the same problem just now, with exactly the same symptoms, on upgrading from stretch (9.8) to Debian buster/testing.

I came across [this thread](https://sane-devel.alioth.debian.narkive.com/Wz1jdd2a/cannot-connect-to-my-fujitsu-scansnap-s1300i), which mentioned the possibility that the scandb daemon was holding on to the scanner. To quote from the thread:

```
Found the culprit....
SANE DID work..... but I had scanbd installed too, so scanbd had the usb
connection with sane and kept the device locked.....
I disabled scanbd, as I remembered installing that and that it might
interfere with SANE... and so it did!
```

But the post didn't suggest any way to verify this hypothesis. I messed around for some time trying to figure out if I could use `fuser` with some device corresponding to the ScanSnap to see if scandb was indeed holding on to it, but could not figure out what device that should be. So finally I decided to just try removing `scandb`, which I was using, as far as I know, so I don't even know why it was installed. After doing

```
apt-get purge scandb
```

the scanner magically started responding. So if that wasn't the problem, it was one hell of a coincidence. So if you have similar problems, try that.

It looks like I did have scandb installed in stretch. As part of my upgrade from stretch to buster on 16th April, I see I have in `term.log`

```
Unpacking scanbd (1.5.1-4) over (1.4.4-1+b2) ...
```

As a tangent, when I was purging `scanbd`, I got a message asking whether   the lines `/etc/inetd.conf` corresponding to `sane-port` should be removed. The default was no, so I went with that. But I'm not really clear what those lines are for, so if you know, please comment.

```
#:OTHER: Other services
sane-port stream tcp nowait saned /usr/sbin/scanbm scanbm
sane-port       stream  tcp     nowait  saned:saned     /usr/sbin/saned saned
```

Also, another indication that there might be something going on with `scandb` was that the messages about it in `journalctl`. `journalctl` goes back to 31st March, I started the install on the afternoon/evening of 15th April. But the first mention of `scanbd` in `journalctl` is on the early morning of 17th April, around the time my `apt-get upgrade` completed:

```
journalctl --unit=scanbd

Apr 17 00:52:18 orwell systemd[1]: Started Scanner button polling Service.
Apr 17 00:52:18 orwell scanbd[4942]: /usr/sbin/scanbd: dbus match type='signal',interface='org.freedesktop.Hal.Manager'
Apr 17 00:52:19 orwell scanbd[4942]: Created directory: /var/lib/snmp/mib_indexes
Apr 17 00:52:30 orwell scanbd[4942]: /usr/sbin/scanbd: no devices, not starting any polling thread
Apr 17 01:40:38 orwell scanbd[4942]: /usr/sbin/scanbd: dbus match type='signal',interface='org.freedesktop.Hal.Manager'
Apr 17 01:40:38 orwell scanbd[4942]: /usr/sbin/scanbd: no devices, not starting any polling thread
Apr 17 01:40:38 orwell systemd[1]: Stopping Scanner button polling Service...
Apr 17 01:40:39 orwell systemd[1]: scanbd.service: Succeeded.
Apr 17 01:40:39 orwell systemd[1]: Stopped Scanner button polling Service.
```

Finally, does anyone know how to figure out whether a process is holding on to a USB scanner, and if so, which one? I'd like to know.